# Double RewriteRule on .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I did a php blog and I would like to have friendly SEO urls for my posts, and also remove .php extension from my urls. So I edited my htaccess file like this :

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [N]

    #second condition and rule
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

So I got my friendly SEO post urls but the second condition doesn't work. But it works when I use it as my first condition. What I did wrong ? Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep first rule as `.php` handler rule but that should check for presence of `.php` file as below:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if not a directory and file.php exists then rewrite file to file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# rewrite every non-file or non-directory to viewpost.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm ! Thanks a lot